# How can I do more things in the API View?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `ServiceCreateAPIView`:

```
class ServiceCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsSuperAdmin]
    queryset = Service.objects.all()
```

and in it, I want to do another thing after I created it.
how can I realize it?

---

**EDIT-01**

My other logic need use the `request` and the created instance. How can I realize my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the created object you can override the [`perform_create`](http://www.cdrf.co/3.7/rest_framework.generics/CreateAPIView.html#perform_create) method:

```
class ServiceCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    ...

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        object = serializer.save()
        # other actions
```

If you don't need the created object you can override the [`post`](http://www.cdrf.co/3.7/rest_framework.generics/CreateAPIView.html#post) method:

```
class ServiceCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # other actions
        return response
```

Comment: in you answer, do you mean we do not need the `serializer_class `, `permission_classes ` and `queryset `?

Comment: No, I've left them out to make the code smaller. I've added 3 dots to show that now.

Comment: How can I get the `request` param in the `perform_create()`?

Comment: You can use `self.request`. This is set [`here`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.base/View/#as_view) in the parent `View` class. Note that `self.args` and `self.kwargs` are also set.

Comment: I have another question, if there is `UpdateAPIView` in the `perform_update`, can I get the instance before `object=serializer.save()`?

Comment: You might be able to use `serializer.instance`, but I'm not sure what you want to do so this might not be the best solution. Please start a new question if you have further problems.